# Get openGLwidget linked with Qtimer update

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyqt, qopenglwidget

I m trying to build a gui with Pyqt5. and withing the gui there is an openGLwidget, that should contain a rotating cube. But i cannot figure out how to make the cube rotate.
Thank you.
this is the setup function

```py
def setupUI(self):
    self.openGLWidget.initializeGL()
    self.openGLWidget.resizeGL(651,551)
    self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL
    self.rotX=10.0
    self.rotY=0.0
    self.rotZ=0.0
    timer = QTimer(self)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.Update) 
    timer.start(1000)
```

and here is the paintGL and update functions:

```py
def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0,1,0)
    self.Cube()
    gluPerspective(45, 651/551, 1, 100.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)
    glRotate(self.rotX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

```py
def Update(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    self.rotX+=10
    self.openGLWidget.paintGL = self.paintGL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different current matrices, see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml). The projection matrix should be set to the current `GL_PROJECTION` and the model view matrix to `GL_MODELVIEW`.
The operations which manipulate the current matrix (like [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml), [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml), [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml)), do not just set a matrix, they specify a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix. Thus you have to set the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) at the begin of every frame, by [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml):

```py
def paintGL(self):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(0,1,0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, 651/551, 1, 100.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -7)
    glRotate(self.rotX, 1, 0, 0)
    self.Cube()
```

Invoke `update()` to update respectively repaint a [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QOpenGLWidget.html):

```py
timer = QTimer(self)
timer.timeout.connect(self.Update) 
timer.start(10)
```

```py
def Update(self):
    self.rotX += 1
    self.openGLWidget.update()
```

[image]